# Can not access rails console on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, console, server

I am trying to access the console to manage my application and it wont let me. what i right is rails console or rails c and i get this:

```
agustin@agustin:~/Agustin/RoRProyect$ rails c
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>': uninitialized constant Test (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:312:in `initialize_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

also, after some time or when i close terminal, my server keeps running but i cant log to my localhost:port and i cant cancell it so i have to restart the computer every time i close that, how can i close it?

Thanks im noob new to ubuntu and ruby so i appreaciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-activesupport-3.2/+bug/1319101).

Run these following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-test-unit
sudo echo require 'test/unit' >> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb
```

And I think using [`RVM`](https://rvm.io/) or [`RBENV`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is a popular practice amongst the Ruby Community to install and maintain ruby versions.

**Install `Ruby` using `RVM`:**

Make sure you have logged in using shell:

*Terminal > Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Check Run command as a login shell*

Install depencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
```

Install `RVM` and `Ruby 2.1.5`

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.5
rvm use 2.1.5 --default
ruby -v
```

To exclude documentation for each package:

```
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
```

Before installing rails you can install node which will come along the v8 JS engine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Finally rails *(optional)*:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: im sorry but i still get the same error, what can it be?
bash: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb: Permission denied

Comment: @Agustin, I can't help you further with the bug, but I have updated my answer with ruby installation steps using rvm. Hope you will find it useful. :)

Comment: um i need your help, it does not fix, i found that that bug can be fixed with entering a line of code, but it does not give me permission to right over the file because it has root as permisor. Can you help me? oh and by the way i have rvm installed and rails and rubby i just dont know how to use it (a fiend of mine installed it)

Comment: Try this in terminal `rvm list default` and what is the output ?

Comment: i htink it is something with permissions

Comment: this is what i get running that 
Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

Comment: the thing is that i cannot access any file within the folder vendor_ruby, i think i might be having trouble with permissions, and that is why i cannot open the console

Comment: Terminal > Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Check Run command as a login shell , then close and open the terminal. :)

Comment: idk how much to thank you, i did this and now im having another error, can u still give me a hand? im sorry for all the trouble but im new to this and i really need to fix this to open the console to start programming. This is what i get : */home/agustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/agustin/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)*

Comment: Okay, now following my steps and fresh install everything, this time everything will work fine. Then let me know. You can knock me at skype(sharvyahmed) if you find it difficult.

Comment: you mean installing the rvm? the steps u put on the post? i dont know how to run the rvm with ruby and use it, is it the same? i know i sound like a retard lol but i have no clue at all of everything i just need to get a project done

Comment: Yes start from installing dependencies step. :)

Comment: Okay i already did everything you told me and it installed everything successfully, now when i try to run through my app rails c it tells me :
**Could not find proper version of railties (3.2.16) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
**

Comment: And if everything goes fine, don't forget to upvote my solution! :P

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!!!! i dont have a reputitation of 15, but i will come back when i get it to upvote for sure, you where LOTS of help i appreaciate everything so much!!! thank u very much and im sorry for lots of trouble

Comment: Great! Good Luck! :) I think you can mark it as solved? Not sure though.